# CakePHP: Keep validation data upon redirect

Tags: validation, cakephp, redirect, registration

I have seen this problem mentioned a lot here, but I couldn't find any satisfactory answer, so  I'll try to formulate it a bit differently:

I have a login form and a registration form for users on the same page (let's call it the "frontpage").

Each form leads to a different controller action. Upon validation, cakephp is trying to display the validation errors in the users/login and users/register Views, but I don't have and I don't want those Views, so I'm forced to do a redirect back to my "frontpage". However, upon redirecting, the validation data is lost.

How do I go about keeping the validation data to be displayed on my frontpage, without having to add separate pages for the login and register functions?

Comment: I found this [Article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/binarycrafts/2010/01/20/persistentvalidation-keeping-your-validation-data-after-redirects-2) regarding persistent validation, but it's very old and seems very complicated, surely cakePHP must have a different way of handling this. I reckon it is not uncommon for multiple functions to share the same View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cakephp keeps its validation errors in

```
$this->ModelName->invalidFields();
```

If you want it to behave persisten the i believe you will have to keep it in a session variable. i.e if your redirects are loosing the property value then try keeping it in a session variable.

Update:

**invalidFields** executes the whole validation process again and **$this->ModelName->validationErrors** should be used instead.

Comment: nope, its $this->ModelName->validationErrors. If you call the above method you are revalidating again (which can have bad side effects). so please correct your answer accordingly - otherwise its faulty.

Comment: Okay, I saved the validationErrors inside my session. But how do I apply them to the view after the redirect?

Comment: Nevermind, it was easy. Now I have this in the beforeFilter of the Controller I redirected to: 

`$this->User->validationErrors=$this->Session->read("validationData");
  $this->Session->delete("validationData");`